# How can I flip around the coordinates inside a multidimensional array in Python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

So I'm making a game very similar to checkers that uses a 10x10 board. Each player has 15 checkers and one player starts on the top left while the other player starts on the bottom right. So far the idea I have for movement is that a player will input the x and y coordinate of the checker he wants to move. However I'd like to "flip" the gameboard each time a player makes a move so a player doesn't have to work with different sides of the board. I don't have much code other than the board itself and the print of the board. If it's any help this is the code I have so far, nothing too fancy.

```
matrix = [[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2], [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2], [0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2]]

print "\n".join(" ".join(str(el) for el in row) for row in matrix)


print matrix[0][0]
```

This is the result:

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2
0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2
```

So theoretically speaking if I wanted to move the checkers on the lowest row I would input x = 0 and y = 4 which would contain a "1" checker. However if the second player wants to move the same checker on their side they would have to input x = 9 and y = 5.

Is there any way to flip the coordinates in a way in which person two also inputs x = 0 and y = 4 to move the last checker. I'd prefer this system because I feel it's a lot less confusing.

Comment: Think about slices. You can reverse a list using mylist[::-1]. Now think about what's your X-axis, and what's your Y-axis. Now can you solve this question?

Comment: Use negative indexing? `matrix[-x-1][-y-1]` should give you the reflection of `matrix[x][y]` over the center of the board. I guess you could use `9-x` and `9-y` to get positive indexes, if you don't mind hard-coding the size of the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want the second user see the following matrix

```
2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0
2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

If that's correct, the easiest way I think is using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

new_matrix = np.fliplr(np.flipud(matrix)) # flip left-right and flip up-down
new_matrix = new_matrix.tolist() # If you want to use a list
                                 # instead a numpy array after the operation
```

Comment: That's exacly what I'm trying to do thanks. Now my only problem is that when I import numpy it gives me this error: "No module named numpy". I'm using python 2.7.10 if that's any help.

Comment: You have to install numpy. Try writing in a terminal ```pip install numpy```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to flip the array everytime, you could just transform the 2nd player input

```
def transform_p2(x,y):
    p2_x = 9-x
    p2_y = 9-y
    return p2_x, p2_y
```